# counting a subset from a finite set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

At a congressional hearing, there are 2n members present. Exactly
n of them are Democrats and n of them are Republicans.  The members want to select a
smaller subcommittee of size n from within those present at the hearing. However, since the
Democrats currently hold majority, they want there to be more Democrats then Republicans
in the committee. In how many ways can you select such a committee? (Hint: Consider two
cases: n odd and n even.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider a bijection $f : D \to R$ where $D$ is the set of Democrats and $R$ is the set of Republicans. So each Democrat is paired up with a Republican. There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways of choosing a committee of size $n$.

If $n$ is odd, then any such committee will have a majority of one party. Observe that a configuration $S$ has a majority of Democrats iff $f(S)$ has majority republicans. That is, if we have a committee, swap out a member for his partner using the function $f$. This gives us $\frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{n}$ matching with a Democrat majority.

Consider $n$ even. We use the principle of inclusion-exclusion here. There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ such committees and we subtract out configurations with an equal number of both parties. We choose $\binom{n}{n/2}$ Republicans and $\binom{n}{n/2}$ Democrats. By rule of product, these selections are independent, so we multiply: $\binom{n}{n/2} \cdot \binom{n}{n/2}$. Thus, there are $\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{n}{n/2} \cdot \binom{n}{n/2}$ configurations where the two parties don't have equal representation. Half of these favor republicans, so we divide out by $2$ to get:

$$\frac{1}{2}(\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{n}{n/2} \cdot \binom{n}{n/2})$$

Comment: In the $n$ odd case, I think you have written $2n \choose 2$ instead of $2n \choose n$. Also in the $n$ even case, $n \choose 2$ should be $2n \choose n$, right?

Comment: Yes indeed! I've fixed it. Sorry for the typos on my part!